# Should event listeners be capturing type when they are pushed as high up the DOM tree as possible?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to limit the number of event listeners on my pages by moving them as high up the DOM tree as possible and using either `e.matches()` on the event target or a map with the DOM reference of the event target as the key to route the events to the correct handlers. It's been working well but I have been used to thinking of events from the bubbling phase only, and wonder if using non-capturing is less efficient in this scenario.

My question is when pushing event listeners up the DOM tree, should they be capturing rather than non-capturing; and, if capturing, will stopping propagation on the event end the rest of the capturing phase and bubbling phase? That is, will the browser stop traversing the DOM looking for elements with event listeners registered, as soon as the event listener fires?

This snippet is quite simple and in the real scenario there are no listeners on the child elements, but I set it up this way to test what takes place when the listener is on the level_1 division and the element of interest in terms of user interaction is the level_3 division.

If the user initiates a mousedown on the level_3 division, the capturing event first fires the level_1 event listener which has an `event.stopPropagation()`. Does this ensure that all capturing and bubbling cease thereupon? It appears that it does because the level_2 event (capturing) and level_3 event (non-capturing) do not fire. This [W3 doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) was helpful but I'm not sure if the capturing, target, and bubbling phases always still take place and any registered listeners are simply ignored, or if the extra work is completely omitted.

In the scenario of having only the listener on the level_1 division, does using capturing really make this anymore efficient than the default of non-capturing? Is it comparable to having a non-capturing listener only on level_3 and stopping its propagation in the bubbling phase?

Thank you.

```js
"use strict";
var l = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="level_"]');

l[0].addEventListener('mousedown', func_1, true);
l[1].addEventListener('mousedown', func_2, true);
l[2].addEventListener('mousedown', func_3, false);

function func_1 (evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  console.log('level 1');
  console.log(evt.target);
  console.log(evt.currentTarget);
}

function func_2 (evt) {
  console.log('level 2');
  console.log(evt.target);
  console.log(evt.currentTarget);
}

function func_3 (evt) {
  console.log('level 3');
  console.log(evt.target);
  console.log(evt.currentTarget);
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  div[class^='level_'] {
   border: 0.1px solid black;
   padding: 50px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }

  div.level_1 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="level_1">
  <div class="level_2">
    <div class="level_3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The browser needs to walk the DOM and build the event's path anyway, but that shouldn't matter. Calling `stopPropagation()` in the capture phase will prevent the handlers attached "below" it from firing, but it won't stop the ones at the same level (i.e another capture handler on the same target), for this you'd need `stopImmediatePropagation()`. However it's generally considered a bad idea to do so. Let the event bubble its whole way and let all the handlers that were supposed to catch it do their job. If you're doing this to improving perfs, you're wasting your time anyway.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks you. Currently, all my listeners are coded as non-capturing and there is no performance issue. I was just curious if I was doing it wrong since there really is only one listener for each event type near the top of the DOM and wondered why should it capture down to the target and bubble back up from it; but it also appeared that the browser was going to do that regardless, and capturing/non-capturing just set the order that listeners were handled when more than one.